# Prove that set is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I should prove that the following is a field: $$\{a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4: a, b, c \in \Bbb Q \}$$ 
Is it enough to prove inverses for + and * here?

I think I can manage to prove that $$\{a + b\sqrt7, a, b \in \Bbb Q \}$$ is a field (by showing inverses, identity and closure) but this one seems a lot more complicated. For instance what is the point of the last term? Why is it there?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The square root of 7 is a root of a quadratic polynomial. For the cube root of 2 you need a cubic.

Comment: The point of the last term is that it allows $a,b,c$ to be rational. If the numbers were only of the form $a+b\sqrt[3]{2}$ with $a,b\in \Bbb Q$, then for instance the product $\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2}$ doesn't have a representation on that form, and the resulting set would therefore not be closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The last term is there because it has to be. For example, if you didn't have the "$c\sqrt[3]{4}$", then how would you show that $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ is an element of your set?

And to answer your question, yes, you need to prove that addition and multiplication of any two elements in your set remain in your set. You need to show that they're associative, commutative, that there exists an additive identity and multiplicative identity. You need to then show that everything has an additive inverse, and everything but zero has a multiplicative inverse.

In other words, you need to verify that your set, together with the standard addition and multiplication satisfy the *defining properties of a field*, which can be found on wikipedia.

The associativity and commutativity come from the fact that your set is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and your addition and multiplication are restrictions of the operations on $\mathbb{C}$, where they are of course associative and commutative. Thus, your additive (resp. multiplicative) identity are 0 (resp. 1), which are easily seen to be in your set.

Thus, the only significant parts of the exercise are showing that your set is closed under addition and multiplication, and demonstrating inverses.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am getting to the bottom of it. Except for the inverses for + and *. I just can't seem to figure out how to actually solve it. 
In the previous case with just two term, finding the inverse was easy. We just needed to multiply the fraction and get rid off the square root in our denominator.. Here with three terms and especially with the $\sqrt[3]x$ it's not so easy anymore.

Comment: @tawi You're basically trying to find inverses in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$. This is like finding inverses in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$. In this ring to find the inverse of say, 8, you want to find some number $k$ such that $8k\equiv 1\mod 23$. Try to extend this idea to the polynomial ring.

Comment: @tawi Actually another point is that you don't have to explicitly find the inverses, you just have to show that inverses exist. If you know about maximal ideals and rings, then the existence of inverse would follow from the fact that $x^2-2$ is irreducible, and hence generates a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: No, not that far yet. 
Here is how I've demonstrated product inverse for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt7]$:
$$\left({a + b \sqrt 2}\right) \left({\dfrac {a - b \sqrt 2} {a^2 - 2b^2}}\right) = 1 = 1 + 0 \sqrt 2$$ From that we can see that product inverse is $\dfrac a {a^2 - 2b^2} - \dfrac {b \sqrt 2} {a^2 - 2b^2}$ and that is is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt 7]$

Isn't here some sort of similar solution?

Comment: @tawi Maybe there is, but I don't know exactly what it would be off hand. If you know that $x^3-2$ is irreducible, then you can use long division of polynomials to show that for any $a + bx+ cx^2$, where must exist a $a' + b'x + c'x^2$ whose product is 1 modulo $x^3-2$.

Comment: @tawi : It is sometimes easiest to multiply two generic terms, set that equal to $1$ and find consequences coefficient by coefficient.  For instance, start with $(a + b \sqrt[3]{2} + c \sqrt[3]{4})(d + e \sqrt[3]{2} + f \sqrt[3]{4})$, multiply out, collect like powers of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and set them equal to $1 + 0 \sqrt[3]{2} + 0 \sqrt[3]{4}$, coefficient by coefficient.  The resulting set of equations are usually not too hard to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{F} = \{a + b\sqrt[3]2 + c\sqrt[3]4, a, b, c \in \Bbb Q \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, it suffices, as you said, to prove that inverses for $+$ and $*$ are contained in $\mathbb{F}$.

The third term isn't there by accident - $\mathbb{F}$ is the smallest field containing both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[3]2$ (notice that $\sqrt[3]4 = (\sqrt[3]2)^2$); it is also a vector space over the field of rationals, $\mathbb{Q}$.
The fact that you need three terms to describe it is a restatement of the fact that $\mathbb{F}$ (as a vector space) has dimension $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, an interesting question is "how do we know that the dimension is three?". This is a consequence of $\mathbb{F}$ being generated by $\sqrt[3]2$. Notice the difference:

We need two terms for $\sqrt 7$, and $\sqrt 7$ is a root of $x^2-7$ (a polynomial of degree $2$);
we need three terms for $\sqrt[3]2$, and $\sqrt[3]2$ is a root of $x^3-2$ (a polynomial of degree $3$).

These are just special cases of a general statement:

> The dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ - that is, the smallest field which contains both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$ - is the degree of the (unique) irreducible monic polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$.

Comment: About the first sentence: don't you also need to prove closure (i.e. $x + y \in \mathbb F$ and $x · y \in \mathbb F$)?

Comment: Yup, I meant $x-y, xy^{-1} \in \mathbb{F}$ which proves both closure and inverses simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $K=\bigl\{a+b\sqrt[3]2+c\sqrt[3]4\mid a,b,c\in\mathbf Q\bigr\}$. You have to checkit is stable by addition and multiplication, contains $0$ and $1$ hence it is a subring of $\mathbf C$.

For the existence of the inverse of an element $x\ne 0$, and consider multiplication by $x$ as an endomorphism of the $\mathbf Q$-vector space $K$. What pproperties does it have?